# Send all records of a Extjs store to server at once

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How can I send my entire store data to the server in one POST call?
It could be in json format.

thanks.

Update:

this is my store code:

```
Ext.define('App.store.consultorio.Receita', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'App.model.consultorio.Receita',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {

        type: 'rest',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        url: 'consultas/receita.json'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set every record in the store dirty, then call sync()

```
store.each(function(record){
    record.setDirty();
});

store.sync();
```

Also, your store is using a RESTful proxy, which by default does not batch actions. See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest-cfg-batchActions

Your store should look like:

```
Ext.define('App.store.consultorio.Receita', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'App.model.consultorio.Receita',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {

        type: 'rest',
        batchActions: true, //<------
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        url: 'consultas/receita.json'
    }
});
```

Comment: But this will call server method for each record.

Comment: no, the default for the AJAX proxy is to batch operations of similar type.  See: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-batchActions

Comment: this is the result: 
http://localhost:3000/consultas/receita.json/2?_dc=1365705540725

http://localhost:3000/consultas/receita.json/3?_dc=1365705540836

http://localhost:3000/consultas/receita.json/4?_dc=1365705540923

Comment: Apears to call 3 times the same action method.

Comment: Is your store's proxy configured to be RESTful? You should post your code if you want better help