# Send all records to server using Ext.data.store of extjs5

Tags: extjs5

I want to send all (inclduing unchanged) records of an [Ext.data.store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) using the [sync](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sync)-method to the server.

In extjs4 you coud do the following (answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954363/send-all-records-of-a-extjs-store-to-server-at-once)):

```
store.each(function(record){
    record.setDirty();
});

store.sync();
```

But in extjs5 the setDirty()-method is deprecated, and I wasn't able to find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could override [getModifiedRecords](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getModifiedRecords) to always return all store records.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add extra field into model, not stored anywhere, and change it before sync.